# Retrieve the latest value with the newest date

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have some records in a table, and I want to get the latest record that has been inserted (looking at date of insertion, which in this case is the column named reg_date).

Right now my query gives me all the records in the table, but I need only see the latest record. I am not able to group by the date, otherwise I'd have the latest date. I tried `GROUP BY MAX(REG_DATE)` which gives an error, because I can't use group by that way. Instead I group by something else, to make it show something. Below is my code

```
select max(reg_date), secretNum 
from REC_HLA
GROUP by secretNum;
```

So again, my wish/goal, is to show only the latest record that has the newest date.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle+greatest-n-per-group

Comment: Simply `order by REG_DATE desc fetch first 1 row`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```
select reg_date, secretNum 
  from REC_HLA
 order by reg_date desc
 fetch first 1 row only
```

Answer (score 1):

below should work for your case, corelated sub-query

```
select * from REC_HLA  t1
where reg_date in (
select max(reg_date)
from REC_HLA t2
where t1.secretNum=t2.secretNum
GROUP by secretNum
)
```